# OrientDB SQL - how to traverse path based on weight?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

Let's say we have a simple graph stored in OrientDB, with an edge type called `weightedEdge` that has a property `weight`. I'd like to be able to traverse from a starting node to an arbitrary depth, but only traverse to nodes that have the *maximum* value of `weight` on their incoming edge compared to all other edges at the same depth. Is this possible using OrientDB SQL?

[image]

So in the given example above, I would only want to hop along the red arrows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use a [let block](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#let-block) and then property selection via [ ]:

```
traverse out()[weight = $maxW] ...
LET $maxW = SELECT max(weight) FROM ...
```